# Getting Javascript error with: $create(Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, reportviewer

We have a report viewer and it adds the following jscript into the aspx file:

```
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {

if (typeof Microsoft == 'undefined' ||
    typeof Microsoft.Reporting == 'undefined' ||
    typeof Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient == 'undefined' ||
    typeof Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer == 'undefined')
    Sys.UI.DomElement.setVisible($get('ReportViewer1_HttpHandlerMissingErrorMessage'), true);
    $create(Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer, {"_internalViewerId":"ReportViewer1_ctl03","id":"ReportViewer1"}, null, null);
});
```

But it keeps on showing a script error 'Microsoft is undefined' when it hits the

```
$create(Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer
```

line.
We've just upgraded from Silverlight 3 / VS2008 to SL4 VS2010 - is there something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the exact same error. I followed the instructions at http://otkfounder.blogspot.com/2007/11/solving-reportviewer-rendering-issue-on.html
but that didn't solve the problem and i still get the error as well.  Give it a shot though, it may work for you...

Comment: Sweet - that appears to have worked, I did the instructions on the root 'Default Web Site' and it *looks* good so far.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line to the web.config inside the system.web   httpHandlers tags

```
  <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

or the token and version you are using.

Comment: how am I supposed to know the token?

Comment: I did it and landed into another problem that this config is causing the problem. So i looked and found add validationintergrated mode to false, And i did that too but after I landed on the first issue again

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
  <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

to `<httpHandlers>` in `<system.web>` (as suggested in one answer above) seems to be a deprecated setting, after I tried that I immediately got a different error:

> HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
>   An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

What I found out is that that the new settings have to be here:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
     <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </handlers>
  ...
```

After adding this to the `Web.config`, the web site worked for me immediately. Hints how to configure the ReportViewer control itself can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx).